# Framework7 formToData not working

Tags: json, forms, html-framework-7

I have a screen login in my aplication and to get the form data in framework i need to use formtoData but it wasnt working, so i decided to create another project and copy paste framework docs script but still isnt working.

Index.html(the test project)

```
        <div class="pages navbar-through toolbar-through">
            <!-- Page, "data-page" contains page name -->
            <div data-page="index" class="page">
                <!-- Scrollable page content -->
                <div class="page-content">

                        <form id="my-form" class="list-block">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                            <div class="item-content">
                                <div class="item-inner">
                                <div class="item-title label">Name</div>
                                <div class="item-input">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        </form>

                        <div class="content-block">
                        <a href="#" class="button form-to-data">Get Form Data</a>
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

js (test project)

```
// Initialize app
var myApp = new Framework7();


// If we need to use custom DOM library, let's save it to $$ variable:
var $$ = Dom7;
 $$('.form-to-data').on('click', function(){
  alert("dwdq");

  var formData = myApp.formToData('#my-form');

  alert(formData);
});
```

Does anyone know why is it not working? thx in advance.

Comment: What you mean by not working ?
alert(formData) isn't showing something like [object Object]?

Comment: They changed the functin instead of formToData now is formToJSON, they dont say that on the official site, i casually discovered that while surfing the net.

Comment: Yeah, they are bad about updating the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They changed the function, instead of formToData now is formToJSON

Answer (score 1):

You can use booth:

formtoData or formToJson will return the same value: [object Object]

Just use `JSON.stringify()` to get the desired result.

```
 $$('.form-to-data').on('click', function(){

    var formData = myApp.formToData('#my-form');
    var formJSON = myApp.formToJSON("#my-form");

    console.log(JSON.stringify(formData));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(formJSON));
});

{"name":"Alexandre"}
{"name":"Alexandre"}
```

Or you can even serialize the form like that:

```
 $$('.form-to-data').on('click', function(){


  var formData = $$.serializeObject(myApp.formToJSON($$("#my-form"))); 

  console.log(formData);
}); 

name=Alexandre
```

Edit: Framework7 got updated to v4, and now it works this way:

```
Single Line: 
   var dados = JSON.stringify(myApp.form.convertToData('#my-form'));
```

Answer (score 0):

They changed the function again, at least in V2. The new function that works for me is:

```
var formData = myApp.form.convertToData("#form-id");
var formString = JSON.stringify(formData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Framework 7 convertToData is ignoring input type text array: for example:

```
<input type="text" name="no_invoice[]" />
```

Removing [] doesn't work either.
F7 only take as array checkbox/radio fields, this bug must be solved.

I solved using javascript:

```
new FormData(your_form);
```